# Share authentication between web applications in core 2.0 mvc using Microsoft Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently trying to setup a second web application that needs to share authentication with the first web application, i.e. logged in users from application A should be automatically authenticated in application B.
Application A uses Microsoft Identity together with Openidconnect middleware to authenticate users.

The workflow is as follows:

1. User navigates to application A and logs in (using openidconnect middleware)
2. User finds link to application B on a page of application A
3. User should automatically be authenticated in application B

I've noticed that the Microsoft Identity cookie gets send to application B, but I don't know how to configure Startup.cs in application B so it can authenticate via that cookie.